# Model with complex/simple properties

Tags: coffeescript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with a number of complex/simple properties that has a corresponding strongly typed view, that calls `EditorFor` to a custom editor template view for the model.

One of the form's requirements is to auto fill the form based on a choose of values from a database.

Previously, I had the selectors on the selection popup do a post back to an action with the additional value needed to `prepopulate` the model, and then the model is bound like normal.

I wanted to see if I could alter the form to do the prefill with Ajax:

I have a `JsonResult` Action that accepts a unique Id, and returns the JSON version of the model.

When you click the selection button this action is invoked via jQuery `$.ajax` post.

Each input on the form has an Id in the form `Id="ModelName_PropertyName"` so parse the keys in the JSON object, using the keys to look up the field in a given selector, and set the values from JSON.

Here is how I invoke from Ajax in CoffeeScript (**I can post the JavaScript if requested**):

```
$.ajax
    type: "POST"
    url: $("#SelectFromPolicyContainer").data "url"
    data: vin
    success: (response) ->
        $("#PropertyInfo").bindFormToJson response.Data.Vehicle, true
        $("#SelectFromPolicyResponse").dialog "close"
```

The Action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult VehicleByVIN(string VinNumber)
{
    return AjaxJsonResponse.Create(UserNotice.NoNotice, new 
    { 
        Vehicle = Policy.Vehicles.SingleOrDefault(p=>p.Info.Vin.Number==VinNumber)
    });
}
```

And the definition of `bindFormToJson`:

```
$ -> $.fn.bindFormToJson = (JsonObject, OverwritePopulatedFields) ->

    selector = $(this).selector

    iterateJson = (JSonObject, FullKey, Seperator, func) ->
        for key, value of JSonObject
            newKey = ""
            if FullKey == ""
                newKey = key
            else
                newKey = FullKey + Seperator + key

            if typeof(value) == "object" 
                iterateJson value, newKey, Seperator, func  
            else 
                func newKey, value

    iterateJson JsonObject, "", "_", (key,value) -> 
        field = $(selector + " #" + key)
        currentValue = field.val()
        if (currentValue and OverwritePopulatedFields) or not currentValue
            field.val(value)
```

Any tips, or things I may have missed or potential problems I might have overlooked would be wonderful.  In my test environment right now though, this is working beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a JavaScript pitfall *per se*, but I'd stay away from using two variable names that are only differentiated by the case of the second letter in a single lexical scope like that. (`JsonObject` vs `JSonObject`)

Also, the bindFormToJson function is re-defining the iterateJson function every time it is called, which a waste of cycles (not egregious, but less than ideal). Using coffeescripts `do` notation is a handy way to create a closure and return a value from it:

```
$ -> $.fn.bindFormToJson = do ->

    iterateJson = (Source, FullKey, Seperator, func) ->
        for key, value of Source
            newKey = ""
            if FullKey == ""
                newKey = key
            else
                newKey = FullKey + Seperator + key

            if typeof(value) == "object" 
                iterateJson value, newKey, Seperator, func  
            else 
                func newKey, value

    return (JsonObject, OverwritePopulatedFields) ->
        selector = $(this).selector
        iterateJson JsonObject, "", "_", (key, value) -> 
            field = $(selector + " #" + key)
            currentValue = field.val()
            if (currentValue and OverwritePopulatedFields) or not currentValue
                field.val(value)
```

The return is unnecessary, but I figured it can't hurt to be explicit about what's happening there.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, and I have made the suggested changes. I hadn't use `do` before, that is very useful.